# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectMode' of undefined" when calling bucket.upload in firebase admin storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to upload some files to cloud storage using the Node Firebase SDK version: "^9.2.0" in a test environment but keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectMode' of undefined".

When calling upload on a bucket in the test environment it fails.
Running the same function in a cloud function works perfectly though.

```
const metadata = {
    metadata: {
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
    },
    contentType: 'image/png',
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
};


await bucket.upload(path.join(__dirname, "image.png"), {
    destination: `users/testUser/documents/image.png`,
    gzip: true,
    metadata: metadata,
});
```

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectMode' of undefined
> at Pumpify.Writable.write (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:292:22)

Node: v12.18.3, NPM version: 6.14.8

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal repro showing how you initialize the SDK, and how to run it.